# Пропала текстура модельки в blender 3.0

Tags: 3d, blender

Пропала текстура модельки в blender 3.0
Сделал рендер картинки, сохранил изображение в папке с сохранением блендера
Хотел переставить свет и камеру чтобы получить другой ракурс но когда начал рендерить то обнаружил что моделька синяя и нет текстуры

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Можешь попытаться отключить эту функцию она отвечает за то куда смотрит модель синяя это нормально красная это внутрь

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]